# Resizing a 3D matrix into a 2D matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following three-dimensional matrix `X` of size `2*2*3`:

```
X = zeros(2, 2, 3);
X(:,:,1) = [1 2; 3 4];
X(:,:,2) = [5 6; 7 8];
X(:,:,3) = [9 10; 11 12];
```

I want to automatically reshape `X` to a two-dimensional matrix of size `6*2` such that I should obtain:

`X_reshaped = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8; 9 10; 11 12]`.

In MATLAB, I am trying to write `X_reshaped = reshape(X, [size(X,1)*size(X,3), size(X,2)])`, but this doesn't give me the desired `X_reshaped` as above.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `permute()` function will allow the array to be reshaped so that the elements are stored in pairs along the first dimension. This allows the `reshape()` function to access those pairs accordingly by default.

```
X = zeros(2, 2, 3); 
X(:,:,1) = [1 2; 3 4];
X(:,:,2) = [5 6; 7 8];
X(:,:,3) = [9 10; 11 12];

reshape(permute(X,[1 3 2]),[6 2])
```

Comment: Hello again! do you know how to transform your solution to python? Thank you.

Comment: What configuration are the arrays in Python? Are they numpy arrays?

Comment: Yes actually they are numpy arrays.

Comment: Can you post the code that generates these arrays? I want to make sure I’m using the same configuration.

Comment: I did it in that way and it works X_permuted = np.transpose(X, (0, 2, 1)); X_permuted.reshape(6,2) . Is this correct? Thank you a lot

Comment: That looks right to me.  I’m a bit rusty on Python.

Comment: Don't worry! BTW I generated the matrices as: X = np.zeros(((2,2,3))); X[:,:,0] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]; X[:,:,1] = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]; X[:,:,2] = [[9, 10], [11, 12]]. I don't know if you have the same settings...